# datagrid colorchange + c#

Tags: c#, winforms

how to change the color of the selected cell in datagrid.im using .net 1.1,and i need it
windows applns.

if i click the a cell in row no 2 then particular cell color should be changed

Comment: This question is very inaccurate... please be more specific

Comment: if i click the a cell in row no 2 then particular cell color 
should be changed

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you are looking for in .NET 1.1 is something like this:

```
DataGridTest.Rows(1).Cells(1).Style.Backcolor = Color.Red
```

---

The .NET2 equivalent would be something like:

```
DataGridViewCellStyle MakeItGreen = new DataGridViewCellStyle;
MakeItGreen.BackColor = Color.Green;

DataGridViewRow row2 = myGrid.Rows(2);
row2.Cells(2).Style = MakeItGreen
```

Or simply:

```
this.myDataGridView[2,3].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

If this is not what you were looking for please provide more information in your question...

Comment: Edited to reflect this. I'm no .net 1.1 expert but this is what i found on msdn